# Format the French number using the directive in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, translation

I am having trouble to implement the French translation for amount field.

I have tried to use the formatNumber which helps to format the numbers but if I do so my numbermask is breaking.

Below is what I tried. How I can handle both French and English number formatting?

In french:
2.00 -> 2,00

when I try with my formatter it become
2->200,
2.00->200
and comma(,) is not allowed too.

When I switch to French I want to handle all the above scenario.

```js
//component

  dollarMask = createNumberMask({
    prefix: '',
    allowDecimal: true,
    integerLimit: 9,
  });
// I am using TextMaskModule import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
commamask = /[^0-9.]/g;


//directive

@Directive({
    selector: '[todecimal]',
})
export class ToDecimalDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    _ngUnsubscribe$: Subject < void > = new Subject < void > ();

    @Input('todecimal') numOfDecimals = 2;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private model: NgControl, private tranalteService: TranslateService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.model.control?.valueChanges
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(() => {
                GeneralUtils.executeJSMacroTask(() => {
                    const newValue = formatNumber(this.model?.control?.value, this.tranalteService.currentLang, '1.2-2');

                    this.model.control?.setValue(newValue, {
                        emitEvent: false,
                        emitModelToViewChange: false,
                        emitViewToModelChange: false,
                    });
                });
            });
    }
```

```html
<input formControlName="value" type="text" class="" 
[textMask]="{ mask: dollarMask }" [fsAsmTextUnmask]="commamask"
[todecimal]="2" />
```